# Can you create jsx elements automatically with a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am teaching myself react and trying to make a calculator. Does anyone know if there is a better way to list all the buttons besides manually putting them all in like the following?

```
          <div className="row">
            <Button clickHandler={this.handleClick}>7</Button>
            <Button clickHandler={this.handleClick}>8</Button>
            <Button>9</Button>
            <Button>÷</Button>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <Button>5</Button>
            <Button>6</Button>
            <Button>7</Button>
            <Button>x</Button>
          </div>
  etc....
```

I wanted to add a clickHandler to each button and to make my code more DRY I wanted to make a new jsx element called ButtonRow that dynamically makes as many buttons as I need because I will pass in an array of chars in `props.vals` but the following doesn't work.

```
const ButtonRow = (props) => (<div className="row" 
  children={
    props.vals.map(val => {
    <Button children={val} clickHandler={props.clickHandler} />
    })
  }
></div>)

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely can, but your syntax is a little off. In your code you are declaring the `<Button />` element but not returning it:

```
props.vals.map(val => {
  <Button ... />
})
```

You need to return the element (note the `()` vs your `{}` for the function body:

```
props.vals.map(val => (
  <Button ... />
))

// or

props.vals.map(val => {
  return <Button ... />
})
```